# Regex pattern force match with condition and not for another condition

Tags: regex, string, match, regex-negation

I am trying to force to match with these conditions:

- If ends with 1,2,3 numbers + 1 space + 1 letter.
- If the pattern matches in the middle of the string, ignore it.

Inputs:

ME001000    RV         **2 B** <- Needs to match

ME001000     G        **10 B** <- Needs to match

ME001000    RE       **321 B** <- Needs to match

MP260000  EQTE         **1 A** <- Needs to match

EL008002P    TR 06 A         1 <- Needs to **NOT** match, because is on the middle of string

Regex Pattern: `([0-9]{1} [A-Z]{1}|[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{1}|[0-9]{3} [A-Z]{1})+(?:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{1}\s)`

1. Part: `([0-9]{1} [A-Z]{1}|[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{1}|[0-9]{3} [A-Z]{1})`: Matching correctly but is also matching with the "06 A" (middle of the last string)
2. Part: `+(?:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{1}\s)`: In order to force the non-matching

What I need to do to force the non-matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you want to use is:

```
\d{1,3} [A-Z]$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9QXPCN/1/)

1. `\d{1,3}` matches from 1 to 3 digits
2. matches a single space.
3. `[A-Z]` matches a capital letter.
4. `$` matches the end of string.

What you needed mostly was the `$` *anchor* to make sure that that what you were looking for was at the end of the string.

The regex demo is using a JavaScript specification (you did not specify what language you are using) and uses flags `g` and `m`. The `g` flag is to look for multiple matches and the `m` flag is for the `$` anchor both match end of line and end of string.

As ggorlen pointed out, you might want to consider a slight modification:

```
\b\d{1,3} [A-Z]$
```

The above ensures that the first digit of the pattern you are trying to match starts on a word boundary (that is, it is preceded by a non-word character or the start of string).

Comment: Keep in mind that this will match `234 A` out of  `foobar234 A`. If you two add the (I think necessary) word boundary means all the posted answers are the same... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ggorlen That's a fair point but it's not entirely clear from the question whether that's an issue but the examples suggest it might be (or that the pattern may need to be preceded specifically by a space). I have added an addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty direct with `\b\d{1,3} [A-Z]$`. Match 1-3 digits starting from a word boundary followed by a space and a capital letter at EOL.

```js
const s = `
ME001000    RV         2 B
ME001000     G        10 B
ME001000    RE       321 B
MP260000  EQTE         1 A
EL008002P    TR 06 A         1
`;

console.log([...s.matchAll(/\b\d{1,3} [A-Z]$/gm)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\d{1,3} [A-Za-z]$
```

- `\d` = any digit
- `{1,3}` = repeat match between 1 and 3 times
- = literal space
- `[A-Za-z]` = any uppercase or lowercase letter
- `$` = assert end of string